# Which is better LOOP before CONDITIONAL or CONDITIONAL before LOOP in a menu type code?

Tags: javascript, performance

Good day,
I currently have a code for applying photo effects from a menu and would like some advice on how to handle it better.

Should I do LOOP before CONDITIONAL like this:

```
function applyFilter(filter){
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var imageData = ctx.getImageData(img.x,img.y,img.width,img.height); 
  var dataArr = imageData.data;

  for(i = 0; i < dataArr.length; i+= 4){
    let color = {
      r : dataArr[i],
      g : dataArr[i+1],
      b : dataArr[i+2],
    }

    if(filter == "negative")
        negateImage(dataArr, i, color)
    else if(filter == "sephia")
        addSephia(dataArr, i, color)
    // else if  some other effects
```

or CONDITIONAL before LOOP like this:

```
function applyFilter(filter){

   if(filter == "negative")
       negateImage()
   else if(filter == "sephia")
      addSephia()
   // else if some other effects

}

function negateImage(){
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var imageData = ctx.getImageData(img.x,img.y,img.width,img.height); 
  var dataArr = imageData.data;

  for(i = 0; i < dataArr.length; i+= 4){
  // negate image algorithm
  }

}
```

Thank you in advance for answering!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the condition only *once* is definitely better performance-wise. That said, the performance impact is likely minimal, especially once branch prediction starts kicking in, *especially* in comparison to other parts of the code. Best to avoid premature optimization unless you've run a performance test and have identified a section of code that needs to run faster - until then, better to write code to be DRY and readable.

You might consider creating a function that calls the `negateImage` or `addSephia` outside of the loop. You may also save the length of the `dataArr`, rather than re-calculate on each iteration:

```
function applyFilter(filter) {
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var imageData = ctx.getImageData(img.x, img.y, img.width, img.height);
  var dataArr = imageData.data;
  const fn = filter === 'negative' ?
    (i, color) => negateImage(dataArr, i, color) :
    (i, color) => addSephia(dataArr, i, color);
  const { length } = dataArr;
  for (let i = 0; i < length; i += 4) {
    fn(
      i,
      {
        r: dataArr[i],
        g: dataArr[i + 1],
        b: dataArr[i + 2],
      }
    );
    // ...
```

(make sure not to implicitly create global variables too - declare the `i` in the `for` loop)

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! I haven't thought about storing the functions on a variable, that helped a lot. Ill be sure to keep the advices in mind.